# SUM() Function not Working in sqLite

Tags: sqlite, select, group-by, sum

We have a table that is like this:

```
Customer  ItemNumber  Item_Name   Qty   FOCQty    
C1          I1           ABC       10     2
C2          I2           BCA       12     2
C3          I1           ABC       3      3 
C4          I2           BCA       05     1
```

But we want it to be like this:

```
ItemNumber  Item_Name   Qty  FOCQty  
I1            ABC       13     5
I2            BCA       17     3
```

We tried the following:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT ItemNumber,Item_Name,sum(Qunatity) as Qunatity1 ,sum(FOCQty) as FOCQty1\
              from   toCSV5\
              Where ItemNumber=?',[this.UpdateItemNumber],SumSuccess,errorCB);
```

but it did not work for us. Please tell us what is wrong in our code.

Comment: your missing group by

Comment: @amdixon yes Please guide to us When we Placed Group by in qry We are new to this

Comment: Add `GROUP BY ItemNumber` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fix**

> - adjust dynamic sql string to add group by on fields `ItemNumber,Item_Name` as below

**static query**

```
SELECT ItemNumber,Item_Name,sum(Qunatity) as Qunatity1 ,sum(FOCQty) as FOCQty1
from   toCSV5
where ItemNumber = 'I1'
group by ItemNumber,Item_Name
;
```

**output**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| ItemNumber | Item_Name | Qunatity1 | FOCQty1 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| I1         | ABC       |        13 |       5 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fdb1/4) link